# How to copy redshift cluster snapshot from one account to another account through script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How to copy a redshift cluster snapshot from one account to another account through script.

Answer (score 1):

To manually migrate an Amazon Redshift cluster to another AWS account, follow these steps:

1. Create a manual snapshot of the cluster you want to migrate.
2. Share the cluster snapshot with another AWS account to view and
   restore the snapshot.
3. Before you copy a snapshot to another region, first enable
   cross-region snapshots.
4. In the destination AWS account, restore the shared cluster snapshot.

Please see
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-redshift/

If you want to do that in a "script" for some reason - then you need to read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/manage-snapshots-api-cli.html
I believe everything you need can be done using aws cli.

Comment: Hi Jon i know the process but i need the same the same to be automated using shell scripting or python.

Comment: OK great - you can use the api / cli section in my answer - take a shot see how far you get then come back here for help when you get stuck